# Bootstrap 3 modal window not working after deployment to IIS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iis, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working in a ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I have decided to use bootstrap modals for some user actions like create and update small entities. The problem is that after deploy my application to my local IIS, **all modals are not displayed**. This problem persists in all my web browsers (Firefox, Chrome and IE) and **there is not any error logged in the consoles**. Please see the follow pictures:

In Visual Studio 2013

[image]

On IIS

[image]

I have **disabled** the **optimizations** editing the **BundleConfig.cs** class

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{     
  // I have added the next line
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
}
```

Now all is working **but without optimizations**. I have direct link to my scripts and css files.

Suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: May be you can use fiddler to check if bootstrap.js file gets downloaded.

Comment: @PankajKapare The bootstrap.js was downloaded correctly. I have updated my question. Thanks for your response.